# Why is formdata returning an empty object?

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, form-data, body-parser

I am trying to send a formdata to my nodejs backend, but my backend prints out an empty object.

I want to send texts and picture using formdata

This is the frontend part of my code

```
  const formdata = new FormData();

  formdata.append("firstname", firstname);
  formdata.append('lastname', lastname);
  formdata.append('phone', phoneNumber);
  formdata.append('address', address);
  formdata.append('town', town);
  formdata.append('city', city);
  formdata.append('itLevel', itLevel);
  formdata.append('smartphone', smartphone);
  formdata.append('mapleOffers', mapleOffers);
  formdata.append('mapleColors', mapleColors);
  formdata.append('reason', reason);

  formdata.append("file", photoID.image, photoID.image.name.replace(/\s/g, ""));

  await Axios.post('/api/apply', formdata, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
```

This is my backend (nodejs)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const uploadFiles = require('./Utils/uploadFile');
var multer  = require('multer')
// var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
var upload = multer()


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;



app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit:'50mb' }))
app.use(upload.array('file')); 

app.use(express.static('client/build'));

app.post('/api/apply', uploadFiles('file'), async(req, res) => {

try {
    const uploadeFiles = req.uploadeFiles
    console.log(uploadeFiles)
    console.log(req.body);  //returns {}
    res.send('ok')
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
}
})

 app.listen(PORT);
```

Any help ??

Comment: When sending files and images use `multipart/form-data` as your Content-Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const formdata = new FormData();
```

Lets start with images

```
formdata.append('image', imageFile);
```

for text

```
formdata.append('userName', 'Fred');
```

then axios request

```
axios({
method: 'post',
url: 'yoururl',   //addyoururl
data: formdata,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
})
.then(function (response) {
    //handle success
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (response) {
    //handle error
    console.log(response);
});
```